# How Can I know which kernel version I am using in Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: grub2, kernel

I want to know my kernel version without using  $ uname -a command or terminal . Is there any way where I can find which kernel version I am using. May be by accessing grub files or something ?

Comment: And why can't you use `uname` or any other command?

Answer (score 1):

1. Look at the `/proc/version` file.

   `cat /proc/version`
2. Look at the contents of the `dmesg` command.

   `dmesg | grep Linux`
3. Look in the kernel/source code directories.

   `ls /boot`

Answer (score 0):

Look at the `/proc/version` file, which contains the kernel version.